# requests.get() returns different HTML than the one on my browser

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Was trying to get links from [this](https://4anime.to/?s=one+piece) website. But noticed the links that I get from parsing are different from the ones that are showing on my browser. There aren't any missing links because both the browser and results from parsing show 14 hyperlinks(for series).
But my browser shows some link which my "result" don't have and my "result" shows some link which my browser doesn't have.

For example my results show a link like

"https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-nenmatsu-tokubetsu-kikaku-mugiwara-no-luffy-oyabun-torimonochou"

but when i searched for the word "torimonochou" in the browser I could not find any match.

Searched for the link in page source(right clicked the page and selected view page source) so i should not be missing anything. Also passed my browser's header in requests.get() so I should be getting the same HTML code.

The code :

```
head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'}

searchResObj = requests.get("https://4anime.to/?s=one+piece", headers = head)
soupObj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(searchResObj.text, features="html.parser")
```

Tried all kinds of different approach to parse links. This is just a simplified version which fetches all the links in the page so I am not missing any.

```
all_a = soupObj.select("a")

for links in all_a:
    print(links.get("href"))
```

Also viewed the HTML code from my compiler. The hyperlinks are indeed different than the ones showing in my browser

```
print(searchResObj.text)
```

So what might be causing this?

Comment: yes might be. but try viewing the page score code and look the part which has the links. pretty sure there are't any JS.

Answer (score 1):

Running this script will print 14 links which show in browser too (maybe you've got Captcha page?):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


searchResObj = requests.get("https://4anime.to/?s=one+piece")
soupObj = BeautifulSoup(searchResObj.text, features="html.parser")

for a in soupObj.select('#headerDIV_95 > a'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-nenmatsu-tokubetsu-kikaku-mugiwara-no-luffy-oyabun-torimonochou
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-straw-hat-theater
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-movie-14-stampede
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-yume-no-soccer-ou
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-mezase-kaizoku-yakyuu-ou
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-umi-no-heso-no-daibouken-hen
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-film-gold
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-heart-of-gold
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-episode-of-sorajima
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-episode-of-sabo
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-episode-of-nami
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-episode-of-merry
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-episode-of-luffy
https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-episode-of-east-blue
```

---

EDIT: Screenshot from "View Source Code":

[image]

Comment: yes like I said there aren't any missing link's. The problem is I get different links when i run the code. Try viewing page source in the browser and look for first link that you printed ```https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece-nenmatsu-tokubetsu-kikaku-mugiwara-no-luffy-oyabun-torimonochou```. you won't find a match but the code you wrote sure did print the link

Comment: @RedwanHossainArnob But I see the link in the source code and in the script as well.

Comment: that can't be right I double checked. source code ? I assume you viewed it from browser? I still can't find the first link you printed in the browser. Try visiting the page not source code you'll see there is no "one-piece-nenmatsu-tokubetsu-kikaku-mugiwara-no-luffy-oyabun-torimonochou"

Comment: @RedwanHossainArnob See the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: this is very weird. tried again with VPN and adblock still can't find it. So tried viewing 933 where you found the link in source. Instead of the link you got I got <a href="https://4anime.to/anime/one-piece">